How to fix autoformat with VS 2022 and Resharper
I have this code:

which gets automatically reformatted into one long line and it is driving me nuts.
When I open resharper's options (no matter which cs-file), it says:

Which apparently means that sections of my options gets overwritten to something else (the yellow parts, I assume):

But I cannot seem to find any .editorconfig file in the path for this file, nor do I want one.
Please help me! What file is overriding my settings in the resharper options, and how to I fix the autoformat to not scrambling my code into 1 single line?
Edit: It happens when I set the closing '}' of the block. Not when I do "format-document".

So going to
[Extensions --> Resharper --> Options --> Environment --> Editor --> Behaviour ]
and under "Typing assist" I remove the checkmark at "Auto-format on closing brace", that removed the immediate problem.
Still don't know how the yellow (overwritten) settings is being overwritten, through.

Can you reproduce the problem when moving both your code and R# settings into a new solution at another location? Did you also check that there is no .editorconfig in any parent folder that gets inherited?

I did check that there is no .editorconfig in any parent folder, yes.
A new solution on another location does not seem to have the problem.
I will need to investigate further down this path of debugging. Thanks!
